# How can I call any method inside a class depending on an input to another method in the same class?

Tags: python, class, methods

I am trying to call a particular method defined inside a class. This calling, however, is dependent on the input of an another method in the same class.

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.exam_score = x

    def math(self):
        print("Hello World!")

    def history(self):
        return "The top score is 12 out of {}.".format(self.exam_score)

    def subject_score(self, func):
        # Call either 'math' method or 'history' method based on input 'func'
        self.__getattribute__(func)()

my_class(30).subject_score('math')
```

Here, I am trying to call the method `math` of class `my_class` by passing `math` as an argument to `subject_score` method.

Running the above code will give out `Hello World!` as the output.

But is there any better way to do this than using `self.__getattribute__(func)()`?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the point.  It would be better to have a dictionary with the methods you want to support and call through that dictionary.  `self.calls = {'math': self.math, 'history': self.history}`.  Easy, safe, no magic required.

Comment: `getattr(self, func)()`

Comment: I have the updated the question and your comments have helped me to try out new ways to solve it. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **`subject_score()`**, you have to return the attribute like this:

```
class my_class:
    ...

    def subject_score(self, func):
        # Call either 'math' method or 'history' method based on input 'func'
        return self.__getattribute__(func)()

my_class(30).subject_score('math')
```

Then you will found the result.

Comment: Thanks! Though I was trying to find out if I could call the method without using `self.__getattribute__(func)()` inside an another method of the class.

Comment: @medium-dimensional: No, you must use `self`.